# How to use @parameter and @Data provider to a single @Test method

Tags: selenium, testng

I actually need to pass in Browser type using @Parameter from TestNG.xml and the test needs to be parameterized with data e.g. Username and Password using @DataProvider

Since I am trying to implement parallel multi browser testing, I am need of this solution

```
@Test(dataProvider="data")
@Parameters("browser")
public void test1(String browser, String uname, String pass){
    System.out.println(browser+uname+pass);         

}   

@DataProvider
public Object[][] data(){       
    String[][] data = new String[2][2];
    data[0][0] = "user1";
    data[0][1] = "pass1";

    data[1][0] = "user2";
    data[1][1] = "pass2";       

    return data;

}
```

Any alternative solution is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since dataprovider requires that the number of columns being passed should match the arguments to the function using the dataprovider, you cannot use browser argument. You can create another method with @BeforeTest annotation and assign the browser value to a class variable and use it any methods you require.

Comment: If I am using beforetest to take in Browser name, is there any way i could pass the browser instance variable from Beforetest to Test method as I am planning to implement parallel browser testing in the project. Every Test should take in a browser variable specific to its method and should not be accessed as a class variable.